CSS Flexbox with a component returning TopBar and SideBar and another one returning main content
I am having troubles getting my main content next to the sidebar in a flexbox layout. My TopBar and SideBar components are combined into a single component, so they are returned in a single parent div. Is there a solution using CSS flexbox or do I have to use grid?
This is basically how it is returned:


<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div id="ParentNav">
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 48px; background-color: blue;">TopBar</div>
    <div style="width: 256px; min-height: calc(100vh - 48px); background-color: grey;">SideBar</div>
  </div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gold;">Main content</div>
</div>



This is what I would like to achieve visually, but I cannot return the TopBar and SideBar seperately.


<div style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 48px; background-color: blue;">TopBar</div>
  <div style="width: 256px; min-height: calc(100vh - 48px); background-color: grey;">SideBar</div>
  <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gold;">Main content</div>
</div>




Is it impossible to delete this element? <div id="ParentNav">

I am afraid not: I have a Nextjs app where my TopBar and SideBar are combined into a single ParentNav component. The TopBar has a button to show or hide the SideBar component. They are combined into ParentNav to isolate Client Components to Server Components. Perhaps there is another solution, but I would rather resolve this issue with css.

Is there a limit to the structural change, and is the style free to apply?

I can't modify the html (unless modifying my components which I'd rather not), but I can style freely in css.

If you can't modify html...
I think it's possible to set the position of the topbar to absolute and match it by giving margin as high as the topbar at the top of the navbar, main content.
As long as the style can be applied freely.
Method 1
position absolute, and margin


.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.top-bar {
  position: absolute;
}

.side-bar {
  margin-top: 48px;
}

.main-content {
  margin-top: 48px;
}
<div class="wrapper" style="display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap;">
  <div id="ParentNav">
    <div class="top-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 48px; background-color: blue;">TopBar</div>
    <div class="side-bar" style="width: 256px; min-height: calc(100vh - 48px); background-color: grey;">SideBar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content" style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gold;">Main content</div>
</div>



Method2
use grid
set the properties as contents so that ParentNav's children can be handled in the grid.
#ParentNav


.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 256px 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 48px 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
}

.wrapper>#ParentNav {
  display: contents;
}

.wrapper>#ParentNav>.top-bar {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.wrapper>#ParentNav>.side-bar {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2;
}

.wrapper>.main-content {
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 2;
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="ParentNav">
    <div class="top-bar" style="width: 100%; height: 48px; background-color: blue;">TopBar</div>
    <div class="side-bar" style="width: 256px; min-height: calc(100vh - 48px); background-color: grey;">SideBar</div>
  </div>
  <div class="main-content" style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gold;">Main content</div>
</div>




Thank you, this works! I find the Method 1 quite elegant. I'm trying to fix 2 issues: a) When I have to scroll due to a lot of content in Main, then the SideBar does not go all the way to the bottom; b) When I reduce the window width, Main goes below the SideBar instead of staying on the right with a horizontal scroll bar.

I managed to solve my 2 issues: a) Using minHeight="calc(100% - 48px)" on .side-bar; b) Setting flex-wrap: nowrap (or removing flex-wrap) and overflow-x: auto in .wrapper

I couldn't help you to the end :( I'm so glad you solved it! If there's a similar issue, I'll try to apply it. Thank you for sharing. @Theo

Yes, you can use
flex-direction: column

to get the required output.
Updated Html file:
<div style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height: 100vh;">
  <div style="width: 100%; height: 48px; background-color: blue;">TopBar</div>
  <div style="display: flex; flex: 1;">
    <div id="ParentNav" style="width: 256px; background-color: grey;">SideBar</div>
    <div style="flex-grow: 1; background-color: gold;">Main content</div>
  </div>
</div>


Unfortunately I can't adjust the html to get the TopBar out of the ParentNav.

I tried and got the correct output, then I shared the solution with you. However, you couldn't change the 'ParentNav' and your negative vote was disappointing to users like me.
